# How must the RabbitMQ Management Plugin be configured to listen on both IPV4 and IPV6

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

The RabbitMq Management Plugin appears to listen only on the IPV4 addresses if the ip is not configured.  The typical configuration shown in the [documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/mochiweb.html) is:

```
[
{rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 12345}]}]}
].
```

The documentation also states:

> Use ip to specify an interface for mochiweb to bind to (giving an IP address as a string or tuple).

From that, if you specify the IPv6 loopback address, such as:

```
[
{rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 12345}, {ip, "::"}]}]}
].
```

it will listen on the IPV6 addresses, but not IPV4.  Specifying an ip of "0.0.0.0" (or omitting the setting) listens on IPV4 only.

The documentation implies that you can use a tuple here, but I have been unsuccessful in understanding what an [erlang tuple](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id70396) is well enough to make this setting and have the management plugin successfully start.

I've tried the following (and other variations) with error messages such as *could_not_start_listener*:

```
{ip, "::", "0.0.0.0"}
{ip, {"::", "0.0.0.0"}}
```

What is the magic necessary for hosting this on both IPV4 and IPV6 endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per a thread in the [rabbitmq-users mailing list](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/64) responded to by @michaelklishin the RabbitMq_Management Plugin is unable to listen on two different endpoints due to the HTTP Server they are using.  Therefore this question's answer is 'not possible' at present.

The plan is to change the underlying HTTP server in the RabbitMq 3.6.0 release, which will hopefully remove this limitation.  For reference, this issue is [#64 - Dual IP stack support](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/64) and the issue to change the web server is [#63 - Move from Webmachine to Cowboy](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/63)